# IntStream, when should I really use sequential() method

Tags: java, java-stream, sequential

When I do this:

```
IntStream i = IntStream.of(5,6,7,1,2,3,4);
//IntStream o =  i.sequential();
i.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I get the same response whether I call sequential or not.Then what are the use cases of sequential() method.

Assuming I am processing millions of ints on multicore machine, unless I call sequential(), is it possible jvm will try to do the processing in parallel?

Comment: I read the documentation and wish to know the usage in real programming to understand.

Comment: No, I just want to know when I really need to call sequential() on stream object.

Comment: I am not trying to sort here and trying to understand the behaviour of calling sequential on a stream in different contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example when you have a parallel stream:

```
IntStream i = IntStream.of(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4);
i.parallel();
i = i.sequential();
i.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Wil always return 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4
But when you remove i.sequential(), you can get other results because it runs in parallel.

Comment: It makes sense now. When I run in parallel, sequence it is getting changed and so I need to call sequential() if I still need to read in the same order. It means calling sequential() has no impact but for in parallel processing. I still feel documentation is not very clear about it or I may have to understand more. Downgrading does not serve any purpose and one must read the question fully and understand its intent.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the javadoc of [`IntStream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-), that method returns a sequential stream. So the `sequential` method will not have any effect.

Learn more about sequential and parallel streams in the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html.

Comment: I would like to see a coding example to see how it will be used whether it is  called in parallel or not.

Comment: @VijayakumarChava The function is just used to make the stream processing happen sequentially instead of in parallel. It's simply the inverse of calling `.parallel()`. Calling `sequential` on an already sequential stream will have no effect.